# How do people get logos to look “drawn” like the first and third logo in the image I provided?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

[image]

What is the best way and process someone does to go about making a logo like that? I have seen people draw a logo and then use “image trace” but is that what people typically do? If they don’t use “image trace” but use the pen tool for example, how do you make it look like someone drew it? How do you get the lines to look like that? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that it **is** in fact **hand drawn** and then just touched up in Photopshop/Illustrator?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW - those look to me like either actually hand drawn or a great deal of effort and planning to give that feeling - one looks like it's a hatch-based imitation of woodblock style texturing, the other looks very like a hand drawing.

You can achieve these looks in Illustrator, in InkScape and in Affinity Designer with time, practise and with brushes; if working in Illustrator you can also purchase plugins from Astute Graphics (Width Scribe, Stylism, Stipplism) which can make achieving this sort of feel a *lot* easier and faster - but.. even then, in all cases, this type of graphic treatment takes a lot of time, practise and skill: there's no quick click a button to get hand drawn effect tool, it's just planning and work.

Answer (score 0):

Those are illustrations made with a lot of patience. There are many tutorials in internet about how to do it. You should look for:

**Vector Engraving Illustration** that simulates the old metal engravings. [Tutorial Link](https://www.retrosupply.co/blogs/tutorials/how-to-create-an-engraved-illustration-effect-in-illustrator)
[image]

**Vector Linocut Illustration** that simulates the linoleum block engravings. [Tutorial Link](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-set-of-art-brushes-you-can-use-to-make-a-linocut-style-illustration--cms-21964)

[image: bird]

For Illustrator there are plenty of **engraving brushes** that make work much easier. [Tutorial link](https://www.retrosupply.co/blogs/tutorials/how-to-get-vintage-engraving-brush-effects-in-illustrator)

[image: Brushes]

Comment: downvoted because for all intent purposes this is a link only answer that basically says, "theres tutorials for that."

Comment: @Ryan In my opinion it is not just a link answer, but a relevant information with the explanation and the links as a third option. In some other questions I have read about the opinion of users and moderators and it is usually explained that maybe the OP doesn't know the exact terminology to access information about what they are looking for, something that maybe the person who answers knows and this can give the exact info, such is the case of my answer.

Comment: Don't forget the OP is asking for ... logos to look "drawn"... or making a logo like that? ... draw a logo and then use "image trace" ... how do you make it look like someone drew it? ... How do you get the lines to look like that? ... In any case does it speak of images simulating **metal engravings** or **linocut**, information given in the answer with a short explanation of each case, to make easier the Internet search. I thought about this when I wrote the answer, that's why I put the links as secondary thing.